# Getting error when running netca and netmgr in Linux

Tags: linux, oracle

When I am running **netca** and **netmgr** processes of Oracle in Linux I am getting the below mentioned error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.BufferedApplet.<init>(Unknown Source)                                         
at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.<init>(NetCA.java:420)                                                     
at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.main(NetCA.java:406)

DISPLAY IS 192.9.200.14:0.0
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: You need _way_ more info for anybody to know how to diagnose that!

Comment: i din't understand plz ellaborate

Comment: before that when i was running these programs i am getting please set the display option ans export display After setting DISPLAY I am getting the above error

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have not exported your DISPLAY when logged in as oracle. Following works on my SUSE Linux Virtual Machine.

As root: xhost +
su - oracle

As oracle: export DISPLAY=:0.0;